# How to translate HTML file locally

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-translate

I have an HTML file that contains some text in English, and I want to translate it into another language. I'm using the google-cloud-translate library in Python, and I have already set up my authentication credentials using the os.environ variable.

Here's the code I'm using to read the HTML file, translate the text, and print the result:

```
from google.cloud import translate_v2
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r"trans.json"
translate_client = translate_v2.Client()

with open("index.html") as f:
    html_content = f.read()

html_english = translate_client.translate(html_content, target_language='hi', format_='html')
print(html_english)
```

This code doesn't works well for my needs because i got `Request payload size exceeds the limit: 204800 bytes.`, I'm curious to know if there are other ways to translate HTML files using Python. Are there any other libraries or tools that can help me achieve this? I'd love to hear about any other solutions that people have found useful. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the Translate API bills per number of chars (as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing)), so one alternative is to send multiple payloads instead of just a single and big one.

another recommendation is to extract only the data to be translate, instead of all HTML tags -- it will reduce the amount of chars being sent and also will reduce the cost.

Some time ago I wrote one prototype similar to your scenario (but for XML instead of HTML). I think you can [base on it](https://github.com/lucianommartins/gcp-TranslateAPI-XML-optimization) to have yours done.

Comment: What other ways are there to translate the page?

Comment: which kind of scenarios are you looking for?

Comment: Translate the html locally and save the translated test inside the new html file without deleting tags, scripts and all information that doesn't apply

Comment: I think it is explained on my answer - if you want to use Translate API, you must build and control the interaction between your local code accessing the local file and the API (as my sample notebook shows).

Comment: It worths mentioning though that there are two Cloud Translation Editions (Basic, v2 [what you used] and Advanced, v3). If you look into the documentation about contents limits (https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#content) you will see that synchronous requests are limited to 5K characters while advanced requests are 30K characters. It may possibly help you too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for information. Also, I have to ask about non Python methods as well. Do you know the other possible ways that i can consider? For example, by using JS or staff like that? For me all the possibilities are good to know